# Login form. I keep getting “invalid login information”

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting error with "invalid login information"

It connects to database because it replies "echo "found";" but somehow can't do anything else.

UPDATE: I know that it shutdowns after the first IF, because I rewrited elses to see where the problem is.

also tried https://bcrypt-generator.com where I put hash from DB and normal password, and it matched.

deleted "mysqli_real_escape_string",but I think it doesn't effect anything in this case.

debugging:

```
print(var_dump($pw,$pedagogove_password, password_verify($pw,$pedagogove_password)));
result: string(8) "heslo123" NULL bool(false)
```

added
`var_dump($entry_pedagogove_login);` into while() loop result:`NULL`

```
if(isset($_POST['form-insert']) and $_POST['form-insert'] == 'sent')
{

    $kod_pedagoga = $_POST['kod_pedagoga'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $cont = false;
    $result_pedagogove_login=mysqli_query($conn,'select * from '._TABLE_PEDAGOGOVE.' where kod_pedagoga="'.$kod_pedagoga.'" limit 1');
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result_pedagogove_login) == 1){ 
      $cont = true;
      while($entry_pedagogove_login=mysqli_fetch_array($result_pedagogove_login))
      {
        var_dump($entry_pedagogove_login);
         $pedagogove_login = $entry_pedagogove_login['kod_pedagoga'];
         $pedagogove_password = $entry_pedagogove_login['password'];
    }
   // echo $kokotina = ($password == $pedagogove_password) ? "jo" : "ne";
    //  print(var_dump($password,$pedagogove_password, password_verify($password,$pedagogove_password))); 
       if($cont and password_verify($password,$pedagogove_password))
       {
         //echo "logged";
         $_SESSION['pedagogove_logged'] = '1';
         $_SESSION['pedagogove_login'] = $pedagogove_login;
         
         
         $location = './admin.php';
         if (!headers_sent())
         {
           Header("Location: $location");
         }
         else
         {
           echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
           echo 'window.location.href="'.$location.'";';
           echo '</script>';
           echo '<noscript>';
           echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$location.'" />';
           echo '</noscript>';
         }
       }
       else
       {
         echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">';
           echo '<p class="text-center">ELSE OD IF PASSWORD_VERIFY</p>';
         echo '</div>';
         show_form();
       }
    }
    else
    {
      echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">';
        echo '<p class="text-center">INVALID LOGIN INFORMATION</p>';
      echo '</div>';
      show_form();
    }
  
    

}
else
{
  show_form();
}
```

Comment: You're getting that message because `password_verify($password,$pedagogove_password)` is returning FALSE and falling through to the `else` block.

Comment: I can't really understand that what you have done here`$result_pedagogove_login=mysqli_query($conn,'select * from '._TABLE_PEDAGOGOVE.' where kod_pedagoga like "'.$kod_pedagoga.'" limit 1');`

Comment: Can we see `password_verify` function?

Comment: Escaping the password is also completely pointless since you're just storing a hash of it anyway. What can happen is that it changes the password.

Comment: What's the size of the password-field in the database?

Comment: You should look into using parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually escaping and injecting the user data into the queries like that. You should also use `=` instead of `like` since you want an exact match. `like` only makes sense if you want to make partial matches (and then have a wild card in the string you pass in).

Comment: I have to ask, when you saved the password in the database, did you actually hash it using `password_hash()`?

Comment: @kmoser yeah i know that, but I can't really know why

Comment: @ZainFarooq just loading my table and password_verify is default php function

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Okay, I deleted the escaping part. The size is set to 200, and I already tried that but it doesn't effect anything

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have just copied hash from another db, I know the password and in the other db it works normally

Comment: Well what hash algorithm is used in that other database? Is your PHP instance configured to use the same? Is the password hash salted? If yes, where is the salt stored?

Comment: @MarkusMüller I copied all php files from other project which is connected to other working db, just did a new db, with new tables and values and I rewrited the table and values in this php file, and used PASSWORD_BCRYPT for password_hash()

Comment: @sqn For debugging purposes, add the output of `var_dump($password,$pedagogove_password, password_verify($password,$pedagogove_password));` to your question.

Comment: @sqn Why is the value of the `$pedagogove_password` variable `NULL`? Please add a `var_dump($entry_pedagogove_login);` inside the `while()` loop (which shouldn't be a `while` loop btw.) where you read the data from MySQL. Add the output to your question.

Comment: @spn Please [edit] your question to show the new source code you have with the debugging `var_dump()` lines. It doesn't make sense that `var_dump($entry_pedagogove_login);` would generate `NULL` when placed *inside* the `while` loop.

Comment: @spn You have a `;` behind the `while()` loop, which breaks everything. Remove it.

Comment: @Progman now it's working, my fail, sorry. Thank you very much for your time!